# Proxy server and IP address blockade

Tags: proxy

i am in china. so i use web freer to use blocked sites like face book and you tube. we use broadband connection provided by our university. some times the server goes too down and we can not use internet. our friends say it goes down because they block our IP address as we use that proxy server. I want to know if that is the real case... should we stop using proxy?? will it help?? is there any other way to use blocked sites with out hampering the internet connection???

Answer (score 2):

You're in a difficult position, because China has a program of "Internet content review" which causes many sites to be inaccessible for periods of time. And most of the information (outside mainland China) which would tell you how to access these sites is also unavailable.

One of the most effective ways of bypassing this is to use SSH's SOCKS proxy feature. This is because SSH is almost never affected by the Internet content review.

This requires you to have access to a Linux (or UNIX) server outside China. For instance you could lease a virtual server from Amazon EC2 or many other [low-end VPS providers](http://www.lowendbox.com/). It also requires you to have SSH installed on your local PC, so you would need to run Linux, or [Cygwin for Windows](http://www.cygwin.com/) for instance. Once set up on both ends, you make a SSH connection from your PC to the Linux server:

```
ssh -D1080 my.server.outside.china.com.au
```

Then you configure your local Web browser to use a SOCKS proxy on `localhost` port `1080`, and all of your Web browsing will be tunnelled through the SSH connection, and the rest of the world will see the connection originating from your leased Linux server in the other country.

It's also possible to use VPN services, though these often get blocked.

A post at our sister site [Super User](https://superuser.com/) has some [more ideas on ways to access blocked sites](https://superuser.com/q/252357/144961).